# php string replace only within html tags ie <here> of a string

Tags: php, javascript, html, str-replace

I have PHP strings that have HTML inside of them, which I am storing inside JavaScript variables for later use.
The problem is that the content of the JavaScript variable is encompassed by `"`s, so any `"`s inside of the PHP string will break the variable.

Right now I have

```
$content=str_replace ('"','&quot;', $phpstring);
```

Which will make all `"`s encoded so that any inside text that I want displayed will work fine,
but the problem is that the `"`s within tags eg `<p id="para1">` will be replaced with `<p id=&quot;para1&quot;>`.
But what I want to do is replace the `"`s within tags ie between `<` and `>`, with a `'`, so that they still work properly, and the `"`s not within tags to be replaced with `&quot;`, like I have it currently.

It works fine right now but that is only because I have changed all of the `"`s in tags by hand.

Comment: I think there is not need to use such a method. How do you set the JavaScript variable?

Comment: print 'var '.$content_id.'="'.$content.'";';

Comment: obviously $content_id contains what I want the variable to be called, and $content contains the html that I was to use,
I am then using it to dynamically change a divs content using the innerHTML function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried addslashes? It might work. Documentation is found here: http://dk.php.net/addslashes

Comment: No that won't work for me, as it is being printed (as in via PHP) so the slashes will just print too and the JavaScript will still not work.

Comment: @Richard: That should actually work, did you try it? It is ok that the slashes are printed as they will be treated as escape character in the context of a JavaScript string (which is what we want).

Comment: oh. well what do you know. It does work. I did not think that javascript would escape characters like that. But I guess it makes sense. Thanks for the answer Muncken. It is very simple which is what I was hoping. I can't vote up yet so anyone who can please vote this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. However you shouldn't need to use it I dont think. You can manually add escape slashes with str_replace or use the [addslashes](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function as mentioned in another answer.